# Filter data in datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, filter

In my code I have a button to filter excel files data "date to date" in datagridview. I want to load filtered data when I click other button, but load button show me all data in excel files, what should I do to load and show only filtered data in datagridview when I click load button.

I mean it is work when I click only filter "date to date" button, but when I click load button it will show me all data. How I keep the filtered data when I click load button.

Here is the code:

```cs
//======================Filter date to date=======================
private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection items = drop_down_sheet.Items;

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            MyClass myClass = (MyClass)item;

            string constr = string.Format(
                "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source ="
                + myClass.Path
                +";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes;\"; ");

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * From[" + myClass.TableName + "]", con);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataTable.Merge(dt);
        }

        string filter = "Datum >= '"
            + startDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            + "' AND Datum <= '"
            + endDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            + "'";

        DataRow[] filteredRows = dataTable.Select(filter);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,
            "Important Note",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Error,
            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    }
}
//===========================Load Data====================================
private void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection items = drop_down_sheet.Items;

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            MyClass myClass = (MyClass)item;
            string constr = string.Format(
                "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source ="
                + myClass.Path +
                ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes;\"; ");

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * From[" + myClass.TableName + "]", con);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

            da.Fill(dataTable);

            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
   {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,
            "Important Note",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Error,
            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    }
}
```

Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if its easier for you but why don't you use AdvanvedDataGridView?
https://github.com/davidegironi/advanceddatagridview

Answer (score 0):

You need to force refreshing data on dataGridView1 by disconnecting the datasource, and then reconecting it again, like below:

```
private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        /* ... */

        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```